# Keep getting error when quitting from django development server

Tags: python, django

I have a django application (Django==1.6.7), which is running fine, after starting it with `./manage.py runserver`

But when I want to close the server, ie I hit ctrl+c I get the following error:

```
 CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in handle
    self.run(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 89, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, args, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 181, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 153, in python_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The server stops, but still i get the error. Do you know why might this happen?

Comment: When you stop your server by `ctrl+c`, it WILL raise `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. You said that server stops, so what is the problem?

Comment: Previously I did not get 20 lines of errors, when I stopped the server via ctrl+c...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you hit ctrl+c. What happens is that when you press ctrl+c Python raises an exception (KeyboardInterrupt), this error stops all running code and in some cases this causes a traceback. Nothing to worry about :-)

If it doesn't happen all the time it might be because you hit ctrl+c right after editing some Python code and Django is still in the process of reloading.